# Chrome could access cross domain API, although there is an error in the Console, why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain

As i said in the title, i'm confused with Chrome when i try to access a cross domain API, details below:

Request snippets:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
  }
};
```

#### Before proxy:

[image]

As you can see, 200 OK and actually got the response data:

[image]

#### After proxy:

[image]

See, the error disappeared and log the correct result.

---

Don't know why. Any help?
`BTW, the same situation didn't happen in Firefox. In Firefox, when i access the cross domain, it won't get any response while there's a cross domain error in the Console.`

Comment: I can assure you, with CORS errors, firefox will still be able to show the response in the developer tools console and network tabs ... those tabs are for debugging ... just because you can see it there does not mean you'll see it in the "page code" - you've fixed CORS, so, no more problem

Comment: @JaromandaX U mean that the network is just designed for check purpose, so the developer tool will automatically do the proxy job for developer, and actually the cross-domain request won't work right ?(Things like i test before, just wanna get a confirmed answer..)

Comment: no, that's not what I said at all

Comment: @JaromandaX 0.0 Could u explain a bit more explicitly ? thx ))

Comment: the developer tools console is able to show more than what is necessarily available to a web page. There is no proxy involved, the request is sent, the response is received, but browsers have adopted the CORS convention to prevent unwanted "cross origin resource sharing" inside a web page

Comment: @JaromandaX right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your response headers you should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` simply solve the issue.